# How to assign one array to another in php, when you have to build the name of the array to be assigned from a string and a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation, variable-assignment

I have some arrays of the form $option_name_options that contain values related to what is in $option_name. I need to pass these arrays to a function in a foreach loop, for which I tried the following:

```
foreach($options as $option_name => $option_value) {

...

$select_options = '$' . $option_name . '_options';

...

}
```

But this assigns the name of the array to $select_options as a string, rather than the array itself, which is what I want. I've tried to find a solution for an hour, no luck yet. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `$tmp = $option_name . '_options'; $select_options = $$tmp;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the $ sign in your string and just assign the name as a string and use variable variable.

```
$select_options = $option_name . '_options';

print_r($$select_options);
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. I also found that I can just put `${$option_name . '_options'}` directly into the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($options as $option_name => $option_value) {
    ...
    $select_options[] = $option_name; //if you want an array of keys from $options
    ...
}
```

Or better solution:

```
    $select_options = array_keys($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$varname = $option_name.'_options';
$select_options = $$varname;
```